# Symmetric integer matrix and odd entry in the diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, symmetric-matrices, integer-lattices

K is a 2N$\times$2N symmetric integer matrix with at least one odd element in the diagonal. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ be a set of integer vectors satisfying the following two properties:

1) $m^{T}K^{-1}m'$ is an integer for any $m,m' \in \mathcal{M}$ .

2) If $l$ is not equivalent to any element of $\mathcal{M}$ then $m^{T}K^{-1}l$ is not an integer for some $m \in \mathcal{M}$.

Let us consider the following set of integer vectors, $\mathcal{L}=\left\{ m+Kx:m\in\mathcal{M},x\in\mathbb{Z}^{2N}\right\}$ . This set forms a 2N-dimensional integer lattice and therefore can be represented as $\mathcal{L}=U\mathbb{Z}^{2N}$, where U is some 2N$\times$2N integer matrix.

Consider the matrix $P\equiv U^{T}K^{-1}U$. Prove that P is an integer matrix and it has at least one odd element on the diagonal.

Comment: What exactly does "generating an integer lattice" mean in this context?  Can we equivalently say that $U$ is [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix)?

Comment: Also, are we meant to infer that $K^{-1}$ is also an integer matrix?

Comment: U is unimodular. $K^{-1}$ need not be an integer matrix.

Comment: I have completely changed the question. I hope it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

$$
K =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
U =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
U^T K^{-1} U =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{5}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Please look at the modified question.